# Pass parameter to service constructor

Tags: angular

Let's suppose I have this Angular 2 service:

```
@Injectable()
class Demo {
    constructor(private instanceSpecificString: string) {
    }
}
```

Notice that its `constructor` accepts an instance-specific `string`. What I mean by that is that I want to instantiate this service multiple times and, each time it gets instantiated, I want to pass it a different `string` based on the context in which the service is instantiated.

**How do I do that?**

P.S. `string` is used as an example, but the parameter could easily be of type `number`, or `boolean` or even some kind of configuration `object`.

Answer (score 4):

The value that gets passed to your service will be determined by the injector that's instantiating it.  You *might* be able to do this in one of your component definitions:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [
        provide(string, {useValue: "someSpecificValue"})
    ]
})
```

However, this has the problem that you're defining a provider for the string token and that could lead to maintainability issues.

It would probably be a better pattern to define some config model for your service:

```
class DemoConfig {
    instanceSpecificString: string;
}
```

And then you could create an instance of that to pass to your service.

```
let config = { instanceSpecificString: "someSpecificValue" }

@Component({
    ...
    providers: [
        provide(DemoConfig, {useExisting: config})
    ]
})
```

Hope this is helpful.  I haven't tried this myself; the services I use in my application are singletons.  Here is the reference that I was using:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/provide-function.html

Comment: What if my service is a transitive dependency of the component? Can I still use `provide`?

Comment: Angular2 uses a hierarchical injector system, meaning that when an injector is creating an instance of your service, it will check for the nearest provider for the token your service requires.  If it doesn't find a definition in the injector its looking at, it will check the parent injector, up to the root injector.  

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: Where does the function "provide()" come from?

Comment: It used to be part of the angular api. They've since changed the syntax to take an object: `{ provide: TypeReference, useValue: objectReference }`.  For more, read here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers

Answer (score 1):

Because the service is declared a injectable (`@Injectable()` annotation) it is a singleton. So instead just remove the annotation from the top of your service to remove that restriction.

This is not necessarily best practices but it will work and compile with AOT enabled.

Example:

Change this service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseSocket extends Socket {   
  protected constructor(
    private baseConfig:SocketIoConfig
    ...   
  ) {
    super();   
  } 
}
```

Into this:

```
export class BaseSocket extends Socket {
  protected constructor(
    private baseConfig:SocketIoConfig
    ...
  ) {
     super();
  }
}
```